# jquery show loading gif in container while load over

Tags: jquery

Here's the simple code that we have

```
<div class="user_side">
<a href="#" class="button white" id="profile">Profile</a>
<a href="#" class="button white" id="listing">Listing</a>
</div>
```

then we have a container:

```
<div id="contentdiv" style="width: 760px; height: 440px;">
</div>
```

and jquery:

```
 $("#profile").click(function(){
    $("#contentdiv").load("content.php?id=<? echo $uid; ?>&show=profile");
 });

 $("#listing").click(function(){
    $("#contentdiv").load("content.php?id=<? echo $uid; ?>&show=listing");
 });
```

We need to show loader.gif inside container when one of the menu icons is clicked. What's the best way to do it. Let us just point out that container is transparent and shouldn't show anything by default.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a css class called `loader` and just append the element before using `load` to the container content.

```
$("#profile").click(function() {
    var element = $("#contentdiv");

    element.html('<div class="loader"></div>');
    element.load("content.php?id=<? echo $uid; ?>&show=profile");
});
```

Other way would be to create the loader div in yout code with `display: none;` and use `show()` and `hide()` to reuse the loader. Like this:

```
$("#profile").click(function() {
    var loader = $(".loader").show();

    $("#contentdiv").load("content.php?id=<? echo $uid; ?>&show=profile", function() {
        loader.hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: one more thing while we are there. do you happen to know how can we pass id variable in that function to show parameter if it contains a common word? Now we have separate jquery function for each button, and we could use one function for all if id contained something - for instance #menu_profile - which would pass 'profile' - or maybe you have some better suggestion? maybe if id is in a class "user_side_menu" it would trigger that function and pass id...

Comment: There are different ways. To use your code above with no html changes you can combine the seletor first, like `$("#profile, #listing").click(function() {});` or for selecting all further links too `$(".user_side a.button").click(function() {});`. Then you could get the id by jQuery's `attr()` function and append them to the url `element.load("content.php?id=<? echo $uid; ?>&show=" + $(this).attr("id"));`. Not the best solution, but it worke for your example.

Comment: great - i tested $(this).attr("id")); version and it worked fine. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add img loader img in content and callback function in load function. When load end, callback function will be executed.

```
<div id="contentdiv" style="width: 760px; height: 440px;">
    <img id="loader" src="load.gif">
</div>

$("#profile").click(function(){
    $("#loader").show();
    $("#contentdiv").load("content.php?id=<? echo $uid;?>&show=profile", function() {
        $("#loader").hide();
    });
});
```